# How do i display only certain part of a dictionary?

Tags: python

I have a dictionary with multiple keys but I only need to print part of it, i don't know how to do it though.

The output i have for my dictionary is:

```
[{'vin': '4T1R11AK7NU637019', 'askPrice': 28106.0, 'msrp': 28106.0, 'mileage': 0.0, 'isNew': True,
 'firstSeen': '2021-11-28', 'lastSeen': '2021-11-28', 'modelName': 'CAMRY', 'brandName': 'TOYOTA', 'year': 2022.0,
 'dealerID': 30873, 'color': 'Celestial Silver Metallic', 'interiorColor': 'Black', 'vinDecode': {(A LOT OF THINGS IN HERE}}},

 {'vin': '4T1G31AK7NU45B292', 'askPrice': 0.0, 'msrp': 0.0, 'mileage': 0.0, 'isNew': True,
  'firstSeen': '2021-11-28', 'lastSeen': '2021-11-28', 'modelName': 'CAMRY', 'brandName': 'TOYOTA', 'year': 2022.0,
  'dealerID': 12750, 'color': 'N/A', 'interiorColor': 'N/A', 'vinDecode': {(A LOT OF THINGS IN HERE}}}]
```

So there are multiple `vin`s and i would just like to print from `vin` to `interiorColor` for every entry; completely ignoring the `vinDecode` part. Is there any way I could do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.pop()` on the dictionary to remove data:

```
for item in items:
    item.pop("vinDecode")
    print(item)
```

Comment: This will remove the vindecode section from the dictionary. This will probably break your code if you are just trying to get an intermediate print to check something before passing the dict on for more processing.

Comment: @LukeNelson good point! If you need to keep the original data, you can use `deepcopy` from the `copy` module.

Comment: Instead of `deepcopy`ing then removing one of the keys using a dictionary comprehension might be a better idea.

Answer (score 3):

Loop over the items in the dict.  Skip the 'vinDecode' key.

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
    if key != 'vinDecode':
        print(f'{key}={value}')
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't do that and you shouldn't anyway because if you can't control the source of this data new keys might appear in the future.

It is best to create a list of keys you are interested in and only print those:

```
my_list_of_dicts = [
    {'vin': '4T1R11AK7NU637019', 'askPrice': 28106.0, 'msrp': 28106.0, 'mileage': 0.0, 'isNew': True,
     'firstSeen': '2021-11-28', 'lastSeen': '2021-11-28', 'modelName': 'CAMRY', 'brandName': 'TOYOTA', 'year': 2022.0,
     'dealerID': 30873, 'color': 'Celestial Silver Metallic', 'interiorColor': 'Black', 'vinDecode': []},
     {'vin': '4T1G31AK7NU45B292', 'askPrice': 0.0, 'msrp': 0.0, 'mileage': 0.0, 'isNew': True,
      'firstSeen': '2021-11-28', 'lastSeen': '2021-11-28', 'modelName': 'CAMRY', 'brandName': 'TOYOTA', 'year': 2022.0,
      'dealerID': 12750, 'color': 'N/A', 'interiorColor': 'N/A', 'vinDecode': []}]

keys_i_am_interested_in = {'vin', 'askPrice', 'interiorColor'}

for d in my_list_of_dicts:
    print({k: v for k, v in d.items() if k in keys_i_am_interested_in})
```

this will print

```
{'vin': '4T1R11AK7NU637019', 'askPrice': 28106.0, 'interiorColor': 'Black'}
{'vin': '4T1G31AK7NU45B292', 'askPrice': 0.0, 'interiorColor': 'N/A'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create modified list containing dictionaries with `vindecode` removed. Later, you can print it.

```py
vin_dict = [{'vin': '4T1R11AK7NU637019', 'askPrice': 28106.0, 'msrp': 28106.0, 'mileage': 0.0, 'isNew': True, 'firstSeen': '2021-11-28', 'lastSeen': '2021-11-28', 'modelName': 'CAMRY', 'brandName': 'TOYOTA', 'year':
2022.0, 'dealerID': 30873, 'color': 'Celestial Silver Metallic', 'interiorColor': 'Black', 'vinDecode': ''}, {'vin': '4T1G31AK7NU45B292', 'askPrice': 0.0, 'msrp': 0.0, 'mileage':
0.0, 'isNew': True, 'firstSeen': '2021-11-28', 'lastSeen': '2021-11-28', 'modelName': 'CAMRY', 'brandName': 'TOYOTA', 'year':
2022.0, 'dealerID': 12750, 'color': 'N/A', 'interiorColor': 'N/A', 'vinDecode': ''}]


# Remove specific Key from Dictionary List
modified_vin_dict = [{key : val for key, val in vin.items() if key != 'vinDecode'} for vin in vin_dict]

for d in modified_vin_dict:
    for k, v in d.items():
        print(f'{k}:{v}')
```